# How should past experiments inform power analysis?

Tags: statistical-power, prior

One crucial step in power analysis is to guess the effect size. Luckily, I do have 1 similar past experiment. So I do have 1 data point instead of completely guessing what the effect size is.

However, it's unclear to me how I can make use of this 1 data point. If I have 100s of data points, I could use them to form a distribution of effect size (i.e. a prior), and do my power analysis for different scenarios, e.g. effect size at 10%, 50%, 90% percentile, etc.

Could I do the same with my 1 past experiment, using its point estimate and SE to form a poor-man prior? If not, how should I use the information from this past experiment in my power analysis?

Comment: What is your experimental design. Are you comparing the mean of one group against a standard? means of two (or more) groups? Or something else? There is always guess-work in balancing sample size against power. It is easier if your new experiment is to use the same methods and kinds of measurements as for an earlier one. But if you already knew _everything_ you wouldn't have to do the new experiment.

Comment: 1. Let's take the simplest case where the new experiment is a straight up replication of the old experiment (same methods, same measurement, same population). How would I conduct the power analysis for the new experiment? 2. In reality, the new experiment is conducted on a slightly different population -- how should the power analysis be adjusted in light of this?

Comment: For a 'power and sample size' computation you need significance level (5%?), desired power $80%, 95%), size of difference you want to detect, and standard deviations of the two groups (should be equal for pooled t test). You might use the sample SDs from the previous experiment. Also, now with a 2nd expt, you may have a better idea what size difference you want to detect. This needs to be given as a number of units (not at as %).

Answer (score 1):

**Previous experiment.** Suppose data and two-sample t test for the previous experiment
were as follows:

```
 summary(x1); length(x1);  sd(x1)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   46.07   47.71   49.93   49.81   51.80   53.46 
 [1] 40
 [1] 2.284828
 summary(x2); length(x2);  sd(x2)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   47.49   50.33   51.64   51.74   52.74   56.24 
 [1] 40
 [1] 1.963967
```

So with sample sizes of $n_1 = n_2 = 40$ you have a difference
in sample means of about $2$ and a standard deviations about $2.$
A two-sample Welch t test easily found a significant difference
with P-value 0.0001. Was this a lucky experiment, or can you
be reasonably sure that sample sizes of 40 are ordinarily
enough to be sure of finding a difference (rejecting $H_0)$
of size about one standard deviation? [Computations in R.]

```
t.test(x1,x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -4.0506, df = 76.28, p-value = 0.0001217
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.8783982 -0.9809154
 sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
 49.81073  51.74038
```

**Power and sample size.** I will show results for a 'power and sample size' procedure in Minitab.
The answer is that the previous experiment with sample sizes of 40,
had plenty of power to detect a difference in group means as large as 2.
For 95% power (probability of rejection) against a difference of this size,
would need 27 subjects in each group. So if you really feel the new experiment will be about the same in terms of variability and difference to detect, you might use $n_1 = n_2 = 30$ for the new experiment.

```
Power and Sample Size 

2-Sample t Test

Testing mean 1 = mean 2 (versus ≠)
Calculating power for mean 1 = mean 2 + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 2

            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
         2      17    0.80      0.807037
         2      27    0.95      0.950077

The sample size is for each group.
```

But the power curve for $n_1 = n_2 = 27$ shows that you would have
slightly less a 50-50 chance of detecting a difference as small as $1$
(half a standard deviation).

[image]

*Notes:* (1) Most statistical software has 'power and sample size' procedures.
I happen to like the output format and graphs from Minitab. Also, there are
online sample size calculators of varying degrees of accuracy and ease of use.

(2) Strictly speaking the procedure in Minitab is for a pooled t test
instead of a Welch two-sample t test. Results should be about the
same if the two groups really do have the same variability.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense, i.e. I know that we can perform power calculation given a postulated effect size and data variance. However, my question is more about what effect size should I postulate given 1 prior experiment? In your example, the estimated effect size is -2 with 95% CI [-2.87, -0.98]. Shouldn't the postulated effect size take into account the uncertainty of the estimated effect size?

Comment: The _true_ effect size will typically not be known until you have data. Hunches based on previous similar experiments may provide a guide as to what to expect. By contrast, the _detectable_ effect size is part of the power computation. Knowing the situation, you might know what effect size is large enough to be of consequence in practice. In that case, then detectable effect size should be as small as the consequential one.// In a month-long program to help people lose weight .5 lbs or .25 kg wouldn't be of much consequence. But you'd want to have a good chance to detect a real 10 lbs loss.